# Ruby prepending static string to a random string?

Tags: ruby, string, random

I figured out how to generate random strings a certain amount of times per line. Now, I'm trying to figure out how to add a fixed, static string to the prefix of all the randomly generated strings.

for example, if this code spits out `gCOABGSS` as a random string, I want to modify the script so it adds for example `HEY-NOW` to each of the outputs, resulting in `HEY-NOWgCOABGSS`

```
def generate_code(number)
  charset = Array('A'..'Z') + Array('a'..'z')
  Array.new(number) { charset.sample }.join
end


5.times { puts generate_code(8) }
```

How to go about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "per line"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to modify the script so it adds for example `HEY-NOW`

```
def generate_code(number)
  charset = Array('A'..'Z') + Array('a'..'z')
  'HEY-NOW' + Array.new(number) { charset.sample }.join
end
```

Answer (score 2):

So simple

```
5.times { puts "HEY-NOW" + generate_code(8) }
```

Or, with string interpolation

```
5.times { puts "HEY-NOW#{generate_code(8)}" }
```